# Why can't I pass around a generic function if I specify the right `Fn` bounds?

Tags: rust

I was answering someone else's question about trying to name the type of, and pass around, a generic function, and I tried writing this code which seems like it's in the spirit of Rust's types and traits:

```rust
use std::fmt::Display;
fn generic_fn<A: Display>(x: A) -> String { format!("→{}←", x) }

fn use_twice<F>(f: F) -> String
where
    F: Fn(i32) -> String,
    F: Fn(f32) -> String,
{
    f(1) + &f(2.0)
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(use_twice(generic_fn));
}
```

However, it fails to compile (on stable Rust 1.52.0):

```rust
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
  --> src/main.rs:13:15
   |
1  | fn generic_fn<A>(x: A) -> A { x }
   | --------------------------- found signature of `fn(i32) -> _`
2  | 
3  | fn use_twice<F>(f: F)
   |    --------- required by a bound in this
...
6  |     F: Fn(f32) -> f32,
   |        -------------- required by this bound in `use_twice`
...
13 |     use_twice(generic_fn);
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^ expected signature of `fn(f32) -> _`
```

I understand that this means the compiler is requiring the `fn` item `generic_fn` to be coerced to a *function pointer* (the partially specified type `fn(f32) -> _`). **But why?** I've heard that `fn` items have unique zero-sized types — why can't `use_twice`'s parameter `f` accept that type? Would it cause some trouble in compiling a different program (e.g. type inference failures) if Rust accepted this code? Is this just something that hasn't been implemented yet?

I know it's not a logical impossibility, because if I write my own trait instead of using `Fn`, then I can explicitly define a generic function that can be passed as a value:

```rust
trait PolyFn1<A> {
    type Output;
    fn apply(&self, x: A) -> Self::Output;
}

use std::fmt::Display;
struct GenericFn;
impl<A: Display> PolyFn1<A> for GenericFn {
    type Output = String;
    fn apply(&self, x: A) -> String { format!("→{}←", x) }
}

fn use_twice<F>(f: F) -> String
where
    F: PolyFn1<i32, Output=String>,
    F: PolyFn1<f32, Output=String>,
{
    f.apply(1) + &f.apply(2.0)
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(use_twice(GenericFn));
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:22] use_twice(GenericFn) = "→1←→2←"
```

Using unstable Rust features, I can even *implement `Fn`* this way:

```rust
#![feature(fn_traits)]
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]
use std::fmt::Display;

struct GenericFn;
impl<A: Display> FnOnce<(A,)> for GenericFn {
    type Output = String;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (A,)) -> String {
        self.call(args)
    }
}
impl<A: Display> FnMut<(A,)> for GenericFn {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: (A,)) -> String {
        self.call(args)
    }
}
impl<A: Display> Fn<(A,)> for GenericFn {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, args: (A,)) -> String {
        format!("→{}←", args.0)
    }
}

fn use_twice<F>(f: F) -> String
where
    F: Fn(i32) -> String,
    F: Fn(f32) -> String,
{
    f(1) + &f(2.0)
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(use_twice(GenericFn));
}
```

Given this, I can restate my question as: **why don't Rust's normal function items work like this?** Why do they have this seemingly avoidable restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is perhaps: why doesn't the concrete type of `generic_fn` offer this?

Because there's no such thing as "the concrete type of `generic_fn`". When you write

```
use_twice(generic_fn)
```

it's really

```
use_twice(generic_fn::<Something>)
```

where `Something` is inferred by the compiler. But if `Something` is `i32`, then `generic_fn::<i32>` doesn't implement `Fn(f32) -> String` and similarly `generic_fn::<f32>` doesn't implement `Fn(i32) -> String`. So there's no `Something` that would work.

Maybe

```
where
    F: for<A> Fn(A) -> String,
```

would work, but that's not supported (yet?).

In the working case you just pass `GenericFn` and there's no type parameter to infer there. It needs to be inferred in `f.apply(1)` and `f.apply(2.0)`, but those are two different places and there's no problem having different type parameters there.

Comment: This answer gets at "why wouldn't it be better to do it the way shown in the question?": because then it would be harder to constrain the function to a specific type, which is usually more useful than having a concrete function value that's polymorphic. Thanks.

Comment: I think another important reason is simply that very few languages with generics and first-class functions have polymorphic function types. Of course Rust does many things differently but nobody did the work on this one yet.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer lies in the struct `GenericFn` NOT being a generic type.

A generic type provides a “recipe” that the compiler uses to construct an actual concrete type that can than be used.

A generic struct `Foo<A>` that is used as
`Foo<Bar>` will be treated by the compiler as a concrete, new, and *distinct* type. Think of it as the compiler creating `FooBar` (the compiler doesn’t really create a name like this, but it’s nicer to see). If you used `Foo<Baz>`, than it would be treated as `FooBaz`, a type that is separate from `FooBar`. This is called monomorphization, and is what allows generic types to be zero-cost, because it compiles down to the same thing a creating a new distinct type.

A generic function is pretty much the same thing, it creates a *distinct fonction pointer* for each different type it is generalized over. `foo<bar>` (where `foo` is `fn foo<A>(x: A) -> A` will give out a pointer, let’s say `1`, to a distinct function of type `fn(bar) -> bar`. *Note that this type is distinct but not unique: `identity<bar>` would give a different pointer, but of the same type.* `foo<baz>` will give a different pointer, say `2`, of type `fn(baz) -> baz`.

Now, a function that wants a type that has both the trait `Fn(bar) -> bar` and `Fn(baz) -> baz`, well a function pointer will not cut it, because it only fulfills one concrete implementation, because it points to only one function: pointer `1` is`fn(bar) -> bar` and that type does not implement `Fn(baz) -> baz`, and vice versa for `2`. You would have to pass two different function pointers, which you do not do.

Your `GenericFn` works because the concrete type actually implements both `PolyFn1<i32>` AND `PolyFn2<f32>`, allowing to pass only one type.

Comment: This sounds plausible, and [the reference seems to agree](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/function-item.html) that "the item types of different functions - different items, or _the same item with different generics_ - are distinct". I'm still interested in hearing _why_ they're designed that way, but that might well be “it's easier to compile correctly”…

Comment: Notice that it wouldn't be _necessary_ for a function item to be generic in this way, because a function item (unlike, say, a closure) implementing `Fn(T)` doesn't ever _contain any values of type `T`_ so there's no practical difference between the representation `struct Foo;` and `struct Foo<T>;` other than the additional type constraints of the latter.

Comment: @KevinReid In the case of static functions, it’s because they are compiled down to pointers that point to concrete machine code. This means you can store two different functions as the same type as long as they have the same signature, which is usually more useful. It could be compiled down to a unique type that generically implements the Fn trait: you’ve shown how with `GenericFn`, but it does not seem as useful: you don’t often need the same function that is implemented for two different types, you could just ask for two different functions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the types are indeed incompatible. You are passing a single function to `use_twice` and that function needs to have a well-defined type, so there is no way that it can handle

```
    F: Fn(i32) -> String,
    F: Fn(f32) -> String,
```

because a single function can't have two different types of arguments it receives. I'm assuming you were hoping it would automatically apply the template twice while still having a single function, but that is not how Rust works.

So revisiting that error

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
  --> src/main.rs:13:15
   |
1  | fn generic_fn<A>(x: A) -> A { x }
   | --------------------------- found signature of `fn(i32) -> _`
2  | 
3  | fn use_twice<F>(f: F)
   |    --------- required by a bound in this
...
6  |     F: Fn(f32) -> f32,
   |        -------------- required by this bound in `use_twice`
...
13 |     use_twice(generic_fn);
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^ expected signature of `fn(f32) -> _`
```

It says that it used `generic_fn::<i32>` and tried to pass that to `use_twice`, but that is not allowed because `generic_fn::<i32>` does not pass `Fn(f32) -> f32`.

So fundamentally your function argument bounds aren't workable and your design needs to change.

Comment: "a single function can't have two different types of arguments it receives" — but the thing `use_twice` is asking for, "a type implementing `Fn`", *can* implement `Fn` for two different types of arguments. I've updated the question with an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting is something called Higher Kinded Types (or their equivalent for functions).

To see what this means, let's first take a look at another example (which does not compile):

```rs
trait Foo {
    type Collection;
    fn make_collection<T>(&self) -> Collection<T>;
}
```

In theory I'd want to be generic over the kind of collection, supporting both `Vec` and `HashSet`, and anything else, however we can't do that. What we'd need is a higher kinded type (in this case it's called a generic associated type): `Vec`. No, not `Vec<T>`, `Vec`. We could say that `Vec` is a "constructor for a type" which takes in as a parameter some type `T` and spits out another type `Vec`.

Note that whenever this feature lands, it'd actually look like this (and hence why in this case it'd be called a Generic Associated Type (GAT)):

```rs
trait Foo {
    type Collection<T>: FromIterator<T>;
    fn make_collection<T>(&self) -> Collection<T>;
}
```

Moving out of type land into function land, we can see it's the same situation as you had:

You want a type that's generic over another type... otherwise called a higher kinded type, however we're talking in terms of functions. Function items have their parameters and return types baked directly into their type.

I won't explain what function items are in this answer, but note that the reasoning applies the same to function pointers: the very type of the function (in this case `F`) encodes the inputs and outputs.

This is why turbofish exists* and feels kind of weird when addressing functions:

```rs
foo::<u8>(0u8)
```

Could be rewritten as

```rs
(foo::<u8>)(0u8)
```

And hence if we had `fn(u8) { foo }` (in pseudocode for fn items) as `F`, it'd become pretty clear where the issue is: the only logical `Fn` trait for this to implement is `Fn(u8)`. We can't get an HKT.

---

This feature, however, has not been implemented yet, and so you'd be better off just passing it in twice:

```rs
use std::fmt::Display;
fn generic_fn<A: Display>(x: A) -> String { format!("→{}←", x) }

fn use_twice<F1, F2>(f_i32: F1, f_f32: F2) -> String
where
    F1: Fn(i32) -> String,
    F2: Fn(f32) -> String,
{
    f(1) + &f(2.0)
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(use_twice(generic_fn, generic_fn));
}
```

---

- *: I have no proof this is why turbofish for functions exists, but it makes sense.

Comment: I understand that Rust doesn't have HKTs, but I don't quite follow how this applies: `use_twice` doesn't require that `F` is generic over any parameters, only that it implements `Fn` for two _specific_ types. My question is perhaps: why doesn't the concrete type of `generic_fn` offer this?